# Error - input expected at most 1 argument, got 3

Tags: python, arguments, traceback

I've set up the following for loop to accept 5 test scores.  I want the loop to prompt the user to enter 5 different scores.  Now I could do this by writing the input "Please enter your next test score", but I'd rather have each inputted score prompt for its associated number.

So, for the first input, I'd like it to display "Please enter your score for test 1", and then for the second score, display "Please enter your score for test 2".  When I try to run this loop, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/Assignment 7.2", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Python32/Assignment 7.2", line 30, in main
    scores = input_scores()
  File "C:/Python32/Assignment 7.2", line 5, in input_scores
    score = int(input('Please enter your score for test', y,' : '))
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

Here's the code

```
def input_scores():
    scores = []
    y = 1
    for num in range(5):
        score = int(input('Please enter your score for test', y, ': '))

        while score < 0 or score > 100:
            print('Error --- all test scores must be between 0 and 100 points')
            score = int(input('Please try again: '))
        scores.append(score)
        y += 1
        return scores
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple (and correct!) way to write what you want:

```
score = int(input('Please enter your score for test ' + str(y) + ': '))
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `input` *does* only want one argument and you are providing three, expecting it to magically join them together :-)

What you need to do is build your three-part string into that one argument, such as with:

```
input("Please enter your score for test %d: " % y)
```

This is how Python does `sprintf`-type string construction. By way of example,

```
"%d / %d = %d" % (42, 7, 42/7)
```

is a way to take those three expressions and turn them into the one string `"42 / 7 = 6"`.

See [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) for a description of how this works. You can also use the more flexible method shown [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html), which could be used as follows:

```
input("Please enter your score for test {0}: ".format(y))
```

Comment: Haha I saw what I did after I typed it.  I was like "Oh, maybe that's it."  I was treating it like a Print function. Though I'm going to look up that nifty % thing you just did, I'm not sure how it works

Comment: @Dustin, http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting but you can also use the more adaptable `{}` method : http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html. I'll add that to the answer.