# difference between " , " and " + " in python

Tags: python-3.5

I was having a problem with some code I was writing. I kept getting the error:
      **input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3**

I found the cause of it on [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969844/error-input-expected-at-most-1-argument-got-3](http://Example). I am going to refer to the code in a stackoverflow links question because it is easier to read.

```
def input_scores():
scores = []
y = 1
for num in range(5):
    score = int(input('Please enter your score for test', y,': '))
    while score < 0 or score > 100:
        print ('Error --- all test scores must be between 0 and 100 points')
        score = int(input('Please try again: '))
    scores.append(score)
    y += 1
     return scores
```

If you replace

`score = int(input('Please enter your score for test', y,': '))` with

```
score = int(input('Please enter your score for test ' + str(y) + ': '))
```

it solves the issue.

My question is why can't you use **,** instead of **+**. I have tried looking online but couldn't find an answer for this specific problem

Answer (score 0):

When you use the commas you're saying run the `input` function with 3 arguments: `'Please enter your score...'`, `y`, and `': '` but because `input` only expects one argument the function outputs an error stating it was expecting 1 argument when you gave it 3.

When you use pluses you're instead running `input` with 1 argument the string `'Please enter your score...' + str(y) + ': '`. The pluses add all of the strings together into one string that then gets fed to input.