# Trying to create a question using a previously given answer (beginner)

Tags: python

```
Name=input("What is your characters name?")
print("                                                        ")

print("Warrior")
print("Knight")
print("Sorcerer")
print("Cleric")

Class=input("What class is", Name ) 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 58, in <module>
    Class=input("What class is", Name ) 
TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 2
 
KeyboardInterrupt

```

Got this response. Please Help

I am new to the software so please refrain from using any advanced jargon.
Thank you.

Comment: You can't concatenate strings like that in an input function, since the input function can only take one argument,
You would need to replace input("What class is", Name )
With something like input(f"What class is {Name}")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error - input expected at most 1 argument, got 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969844/error-input-expected-at-most-1-argument-got-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because the `input` isn't like `print`, you can't pass multiple arguments and it joins them in spaces, so you should do:

```
Name=input("What is your characters name?")
print("                                                        ")

print("Warrior")
print("Knight")
print("Sorcerer")
print("Cleric")

Class=input(f"What class is {Name}" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to combine the two strings, also known as concatenation

```py
Class = input("What class is " + Name)
```

A format string would probably be easier to read though

```py
Class = input(f"What class is {Name}")
```

I suspect the reason why you tried what you did is because it's possible to pass multiple arguments to the `print` function. This mostly only works for `print`. It won't work for most of Python's built-in functions.

By the way, while you're here, variable names usually start with lowercase letters. It will work either way, but it looks nice when the variable names are consistent.

Comment: thank you, I have altered the variables and fixed the code.